# More efficient way to implement a CYOA game instead of using switch

Tags: javascript, tree, switch-statement

I'm trying to implement a function that will return a result (blue text) based on the combination of choices according to this tree diagram:

[image: tree diagram of choices]

I currently have three functions:

- `optionA` click - handles the left option click using switch
- `optionB` click - handles the right option click using switch
- `reset` click - resets everything to initial state

This approach works fine but I was wondering if there is a more effective way of achieving the same result. My current code is not really scalable. It's repetitive and I think it could potentially be shortened but I'm not really sure how to approach it.

```js
let optA = document.querySelector(".optionA");
let optB = document.querySelector(".optionB");
let result = document.querySelector(".result");
let reset = document.querySelector(".reset")

function handleOptAClick() {
  if (result.innerHTML === '') {
    switch (optA.innerHTML) {
      case 'Hot':
        optA.innerHTML = "Leaf";
        optB.innerHTML = "Flower";
        break;
      case 'Leaf':
        optA.innerHTML = "Pure";
        optB.innerHTML = "Blend";
        break;
      case 'Alcohol':
        optA.innerHTML = "Plum";
        optB.innerHTML = "Rice";
        break;
      case 'Pure':
        optA.innerHTML = "Sunlight";
        optB.innerHTML = "Shade";
        break;
      case 'Plum':
        result.innerHTML = "Umeshu";
        break;
      case 'Bacteria':
        optA.innerHTML = "Yeast";
        optB.innerHTML = "Milk";
        break;
      case 'Sunlight':
        result.innerHTML = "Sencha";
        break;
      case 'Yeast':
        result.innerHTML = "Kombucha"
        break;
      default: 
        console.log("Something went wrong");
    }
  }
}

function handleOptBClick() {
  if (result.innerHTML === '') {
     switch (optB.innerHTML) {
    case 'Cold':
      optA.innerHTML = "Alcohol";
      optB.innerHTML = "Soft";
      break;
    case 'Flower':
      result.innerHTML = "Sakura"
      break;
    case 'Soft':
      optA.innerHTML = "Bacteria";
      optB.innerHTML = "Soy";
      break;
    case 'Blend':
      result.innerHTML = "Genmaicha"
      break;
    case 'Rice':
      result.innerHTML = "Sake"
      break;
    case 'Soy':
      result.innerHTML = "Soymilk"
      break;
    case 'Plum':
      result.innerHTML = "Umeshu";
      break;
    case 'Shade':
      result.innerHTML = "Matcha";
      break;
    case 'Milk':
      result.innerHTML = "Yakuruto";
      break;
    default: 
      console.log("Something went wrong");
     }
  }
}

function handleResetClick() {
  optA.innerHTML = "Hot";
  optB.innerHTML = "Cold";
  result.innerHTML = '';
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button class="optionA" onClick=handleOptAClick()>Hot</button>
  <button class="optionB" onClick=handleOptBClick()>Cold</button>
  <button class="reset" onClick=handleResetClick()>Reset</button>
  <p class="result"></p>
</div>
```

I'm thankful for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is quite some repetition in your code. You could improve it by making a data structure to represent the tree, instead of hard-coding every parent-child relation in the code.

For instance, a tree node could be an array with three elements: the choice (to be displayed), the (nested) tree node for the left choice, and the (nested) tree node for the right choice. A leaf in the tree would be an array with only two entries: the choice (to be displayed) and the corresponding result to be displayed.

The code could then focus on maintaining a reference to what is the current node in the tree, i.e. the node that corresponds with the choices that were made up to this point.

I would also suggest to not define the click handlers with HTML attributes, but with code (using `addEventListener`).

Here is how that would look:

```js
const tree = 
["Root",
    ["Hot",
        ["Leaf",
            ["Pure",
                ["Sunlight", "Sencha"],
                ["Shade", "Matcha"]
            ],
            ["Blend", "Genmaicha"]
        ],
        ["Flower", "Sakura"]
    ],
    ["Cold",
        ["Alcohol",
            ["Plum", "Umeshu"],
            ["Rice", "Sake"]
        ],
        ["Soft",
            ["Bacteria",
                ["Yeast", "Kombucha"],
                ["Milk", "Yakuruto"]
            ],
            ["Soy", "Soymilk"]
        ]
    ]
];

let current = tree;

const [left, right] = document.querySelectorAll(".option");
const result = document.querySelector(".result");
const reset = document.querySelector(".reset")

left.addEventListener("click", () => choose(current[1]));
right.addEventListener("click", () => choose(current[2]));
reset.addEventListener("click", () => choose(tree));

function choose(choice) {
    if (choice.length == 2) { // We're at a leaf
        result.textContent = choice[1];
    } else {
        current = choice;
        left.textContent = current[1][0];
        right.textContent = current[2][0];
        result.textContent = "";
    }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button class="option">Hot</button>
  <button class="option">Cold</button>
  <button class="reset">Reset</button>
  <p class="result"></p>
</div>
```